# https://localhost:7002 not accessible from IE but same works in firefox and chrome

Tags: internet-explorer-8, localhost, weblogic-10.x

I am not able to access `https://localhost:7002` form IE8. I have started the server(Weblogic) and I am able to access same from Firefox and Chrome. I use the same proxy in Chrome and IE8.

IE shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" when i hit local host.

I have the "Bypass proxy for local" and "auto detect" enabled. Host entry for local host is also available.

`http://localhost:7001` is working from IE but `https://localhost:7002` is not. But both work from firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved.  I had to uninstall below windows updates:

•   KB2900986
•   KB2888505
•   KB2876331
•   KB2868626